# Programmatically modify array | Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to take data that I have collected through a REST API and decrypt is against a salt/pepper that I have already created. The below function, when `$value` is an array of objects, only returns the last object in the array.

`encryption.decrypt()` returns a string.

**UPDATE** have updated code with comments and I am still receiving an object instead of an array of objects.

```
sharedServices.encryption.decrypt = function($value) {
    if(typeof $value === 'object' && $value !== null) {
        $result = {};
        for(var $key in $value) {
            $result[$key] = sharedServices.encryption.decrypt($value[$key]);
        }
        return $result;
    } else if(Array.isArray($value)) {
        $result = new Array();
        for(var $i of $value) {
            $result[$i] = sharedServices.encryption.decrypt($value[$i]);
        }
        return $result;
    } else {
        $pepperSalt = sharedServices.encryption.pepper + "3" + sharedServices.encryption.salt;
        let encryption = new Encryption();
        return encryption.decrypt($value, $pepperSalt);
    }
};
```

Comment: Naming all variables with `$` is really confusing… =_=

Comment: I'm not sure what else is going on, but you may want to use `for(var $key of $value)` (rather than `for(var $key in $value)`) since you know `$value` is an Array at that point. And it may introduce some fragility to have your function return an object (`$result`) sometimes and a string (`encryption.decrypt($value, $pepperSalt);`) other times, but if the invoking context is ready for this, then I guess it can work fine.

Comment: Don't you want your `result` to be an array as well when the input is an array?

Comment: It should be returning the exact same as what was inputted, same structure and typeof except that it is now decrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working in the end. It now loops through objects and array preforming a function when ever it find a string/integer

```
    sharedServices.functions.drill({
        object:value, 
        params:{},
        function: function(value, params) {return value;}
    });

    sharedServices.functions.drill = function(options) {
            var result = null;
            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(options.object) == '[object Array]') {
                result = [];
                angular.forEach(options.object, 
                    function(value, key) {
                        console.log(key);
                        result.push(
                            sharedServices.functions.drill(
                                {
                                    object: value,
                                    params: options.params,
                                    function: options.function
                                }
                            )
                        )
                    }
                );
            } else if(Object.prototype.toString.call(options.object) == '[object Object]') {
                result = {};
                for(var key in options.object) {
                    result[key] = 
                    sharedServices.functions.drill(
                        {
                            object:options.object[key],
                            params: options.params,
                            function: options.function
                        }
                    );
                }
            } else {
                result = options.function(options.object,options.params);
            }
            return result;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if statement` to check object or not is matched for array as well (Array is an object and all that). what i mean is you are always hitting the first IF for both Object & Array.

So you can switch the first and second if's, or properly check its object and not array for first `if statement`

Comment: No changes I'm afraid